# How to discard Promise type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using TypeScript and I have the following promise chain:

```
function bar(): Promise<boolean> {
    globalVar = doSomething();
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}

return foo()
    .then(() => {
        return bar();
    }).then(() => {
        return bas();
    }
```

In most cases, I need the return value of `bas`, but in one case I don't need it. What is the best way to discard the `boolean` type? I tried a cast like `as Promise<void>` but it doesn't work as the types `void` and `boolean` don't intersect.

Here is a minimal MVCE:

```
let globalVar: string = 'hello';

function bar(): Promise<boolean> {
    globalVar = 'world';
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
function xyz(): Promise<void> {
    return bar();
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA5sD2BGBDYA1RAnAXBAzmdAlgHZQQC8EA5ABYjByUDcAsAFBsBmArkQMZgFYRCEnQAKAJTYACulgBbAjhAAeeLFihERAHwQA3mwjHocJKgzkqAd1jpgAEyZGT6cF3TDZCpSAB0bjiaAG4gYvhcIBIsrAC+nDz8gsIAHgCeAF6SMnKKyirBsAQOeoasJhBuYB7CopIxsUA)

Comment: Just write `bas()` instead of `return bas()`?  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (this is a link to your code in a web IDE)](//tsplay.dev/NDGVxw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, with no syntax errors or undeclared variables or functions.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] that shows a complete code flow containing both cases. The way you write it now the only thing that could be suggested is to use either `Promise<any>` or `Promise<boolean|void>` but it is not clear if any of those ways are a good suggestion (`Promise<any>` certainly not, and `Promise<boolean|void>` might be a way do deal with it, but probably also just a Q&D solution)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your input, but that would be wrong. It would break the promise chain execution order. The order in which the functions are executed needs to be preserved

Comment: @HelloWorld just show a [mcve] that is fully typed for both code flows you want to have unified, as two separate code snippets.

Comment: @t.niese I added an MVCE

Comment: Ah okay I see what you're talking about now, thanks for the example code

Comment: @HelloWorld can you use `await`/`async`?

Comment: I try to avoid it if possible, only last option :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a `.then` behind your `bar()` that returns nothing:

```
let globalVar: string = 'hello';

function bar(): Promise<boolean> {
    globalVar = 'world';
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
function xyz(): Promise<void> {
    return bar().then(() => undefined);
    /*
       // other possible callbacks
       return bar().then(() => {});
       return bar().then(() => {
          return;
       });
    */
}
```

With `await`/`async` it would look better:

```
let globalVar: string = 'hello';

function bar(): Promise<boolean> {
    globalVar = 'world';
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
async function xyz(): Promise<void> {
    await bar()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I thought about it, but wasn't sure if that's the intended way. Thanks a lot for the confirmation!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You might be right, for some reason I like the await/async here as an exceptional use-case

Comment: @HelloWorld I wouldn't use `await`/`async` just as an exceptional use case. If you can use `await`/`async` it would use that always instead of chaining.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification, just for readability?

Comment: Btw, I also found this https://kyrylkov.com/2017/04/25/native-promises-async-functions-nodejs-8-performance/ It seems promise chains are still slightly faster

Comment: @HelloWorld that article is from 2017 and node 8. We are currently at 14LTS and 16.

Answer (score 3):

This is a longstanding bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#12871](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12871).  It's listed as being on the "Backlog" so I wouldn't expect to see a fix anytime soon if I were you.  The easiest way to address this is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling a "cast") to suppress the error:

```
function xyz(): Promise<void> {
    return bar() as Promise<any> as Promise<void>;
}
```

the error on `bar() as Promise<void>` is just because the compiler doesn't see them as sufficiently related to do an assertion; all you have to do is assert to some intermediate type seen as related to both of them.

This change has the advantage of leaving the emitted JavaScript alone.

---

Another fix is to use an empty `then()`, which doesn't change the returned promise (it'll still be a `boolean` at runtime) but the compiler sees it as `Promise<void>`:

```
function uvw(): Promise<void> {
    return bar().then()
}
```

Or you could explicitly make sure there's no return value at runtime too:

```
function rst(): Promise<void> {
    return bar().then(() => { })
}
```

But both of these are just runtime-visible workarounds for a TS compiler bug, so I don't know if I recommend them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA5sD2BGBDYA1RAnAXBAzmdAlgHZQQC8EA5ABYjByUDcAsAFBsBmArkQMZgFYRCEnQAKAJTYACulgBbAjhAAeeLFihERAHwQA3mwjHocJKgzkqAd1jpgAEyZGT6cF3TDZCpSAB0bjiaAG4gYvhcIBIsrAC+nDz8gsIAHgCeAF6SMnKKyirBsAQOeoasJhBuYB7CopIQiDgQ3nmq2ml6jc25vgVFJTHx7KzcfAJCEFzB1tndPvmFxaUuxlU1IhiSfmC0RJJsQwljyZV4sy29iyUGK5XunhviEtu7YvVkpRCxEgdsbEA)

Comment: I originally also suggested `return bar().then()` but wouldn't that potentially break the code in the future? I don't know TS that well to be able to decide that the compiler accepting it should be considered a bug of the compiler itself.

Comment: I mean sure if they fix `#12871` before the detection of `return bar().then()` being actually wrong it won't be a problem. If it is the other way round it might be a problem.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the follow up! These are great insights!!